# When explicit "else" is necessary in control structures?

Tags: php, algorithm

What should one use?
This, *without* else:

```
function($condition) {
    if($condition) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or this, *with* an else:

```
function($condition) {
    if($condition) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What are potential drawbacks?

Note: I understand that right solution for *this very example* would be

```
function($condition) {
    return (boolean)$condition;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases it is possible to increase readability by setting "else" aside. Two examples below are eqiuvalent. Second produces less code, though it will suit only when we return values without complex calculations in that block, but again, we can utilize functions to make it usable.

```
function($a, $b) {
    if($a) {
        if($a > $b) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function($a, $b) {
    if($a) {
        if($a > $b) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: if not speaking about general cases with more complex conditions assumption, *this* should fold to:

```
function($a, $b) {
    return ($a and $a > $b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this approach:

```
function($condition) {
    $retValue = false;
    if($condition) {
        $retValue = true;
    }
    return $retValue;
}
```

This way you know where this function will return, (always at the end) which is good for later analyzing. You set a default value and only change it if the condition is right.

Comment: Its better to use it like as `function($condition) {
    return ($condition) ? true : false;
}`

Comment: I assume it's a generic question, and that he might want to do other things in the code blocks apart from returning true and false. Otherwise your solution can be reduced to  `function($condition) { return $condition; }`

Answer (score 0):

With else there is a better readability. However, both the functions are doing the same as the function is terminated by the return function. I find it also safer to use the else if in some cases you can forget using the return function which then go further to return the false.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the else too, for these reasons:

1. Your code is better readable
2. In complex code, like when you use if/else within other if/else's, debugging will be much easier.

Answer (score -2):

In the first one both true and false will be returned, as when the if statement finishes, it will go and do the very next thing, return false. In the second one, one true OR false will be returned, depending on the condition. Draw backs for the first one would be that you get both true and false returned, which could confuse a function that's only asking for one parameter, and receiving two instead. This is assuming that you include this inside a larger function. I'm not sure why you would want to use the first one though. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: But [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) says, that _return statement immediately ends execution of the current function_, thereby prevents double return.

Comment: Both return won't be executed as a return statement ens the execution of the function. So in a function no code is executed after a return.